# How to manually render an image to ImageReader Surface?

Tags: android, android-camera2, image-reader

I want to manually render the raw bytes of an image (`byte[]`) to the `Surface` provided by ImageReader.
Let's assume there is an ImageReader configured as follows:

```java
var reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
var surface = reader.getSurface();
```

Is it possible to manually send the raw bytes of an image to the `Surface` so that the image can be obtained from the reader using `reader.acquireNextImage()`? Typically, this is handled by the CameraDevice or MediaCodec. However, I have a use case where I need to send an image manually.

I tried drawing a bitmap to the `Canvas` object,

```java
Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas(null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

In this case, `reader.acquireNextImage()` successfully returns an `Image` object, but attempting to access the planes with `image.getPlanes()` results in a crash with the following exception.

```
.....................
runtime.cc:669]   native: #07 pc 0000000000006f14  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+312)
runtime.cc:669]   native: #08 pc 000000000000284c  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni_utils.so (android::getLockedImageInfo(android::CpuConsumer::LockedBuffer*, int, int, unsigned char**, unsigned int*, int*, int*)+1764)
runtime.cc:669]   native: #09 pc 0000000000041ad4  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (Image_createSurfacePlanes(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, int, int, unsigned long)+916)
runtime.cc:669]   native: #10 pc 0000000000222244  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148)
runtime.cc:669]   native: #11 pc 0000000000212b80  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (nterp_helper+5648)
runtime.cc:669]   native: #12 pc 000000000054131a  [anon:dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex] (android.media.ImageReader$SurfaceImage.getPlanes+50)
......................
```